# How to avoid lift in MaybeT and why the final validation is not effective?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, option-type

How can we avoid - if it makes sense to do so.. - the use of `lift` in `MaybeT`?

Classical example from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Passphrase_validation,_simplified).

Given

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid s = length s >= 8
            && any isAlpha s
            && any isNumber s
            && any isPunctuation s
```

We have

```
getPassphrase :: MaybeT IO String
getPassphrase = do s <- lift getLine
                   guard (isValid s) -- Alternative provides guard.
                   return s

askPassphrase :: MaybeT IO ()
askPassphrase = do lift $ putStrLn "Insert your new passphrase:"
                   value <- getPassphrase
                   lift $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

### What I've tried

I guess I need to use `ask` and `tell`, so I've transformed the code as follows:

```
getPassphrase :: MaybeT (ReaderT String IO) String
getPassphrase = do 
        s <- ask
        guard (isValid s) -- Alternative provides guard.
        return s

askPassphrase :: MaybeT (ReaderT String IO) ()
askPassphrase = do 
  -- _ <- tell "Insert your new passphrase:"
  value <-  getPassphrase
  -- _ <- tell "Storing in database..."
  return ()



main :: IO (Maybe ())
main =
  runReaderT (runMaybeT askPassphrase) "test123!"
```

The string `"test123!"` produces `Just()` while `"test123"` returns `Nothing`, so IMO **it does work as expected, but I still have to include the Writer.**

If I do

```
askPassphrase :: MaybeT (ReaderT String (WriterT String IO)) ()
askPassphrase = do 
  _ <- tell "Insert your new passphrase:"
  let value =  getPassphrase
  _ <- tell "Storing in database..."
  return ()



main :: IO ()
main =
  execWriterT (runReaderT (runMaybeT askPassphrase) "test123!") >>= putStrLn
```

it compiles and run but something goes wrong because any string is considered valid, I mean that I always see `"Insert your new passphrase:Storing in database..."` in the output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to find the correct types of my functions with a `:t` command and then specify them, they are

```
getPassphrase :: MaybeT (ReaderT String (WriterT String IO)) [Char]
getPassphrase = do
```

and

```
askPassphrase :: MaybeT (ReaderT String (WriterT String IO)) ()
askPassphrase = do
```

And `lift`**can be avoided**! (`ask` was already without `lift` in the second part of the question)

```
askPassphrase = do 
  tell "Insert your new passphrase:"
  value <-  getPassphrase
  tell "Storing in database..."
```

Online version [here](https://repl.it/repls/FittingHummingKeyboardmacro).